# How do I extract contents form a swfobject htm page?

Tags: flash

I want to extract the photos in some page. However, when I load the page source, I can't find any .swf file, or rather any other files :( 
I'm not really a graphic designer so I wouldn't know much, so I hope someone kind will be able to help me! :D

Here are the page I'm talking about: http://modernlove.co.kr/gatalogview/2014ss_catalog_wide2/index.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the page's source code you will notice the swf path:
`FlashObject("swf/gallery02.swf",1200, 860,"#ffffff","index")`

You can do that using the command `CTRL+U` (`Control+U` on MAC), assuming you are using Google Chrome.

Now we know the swf location. It's in the same path as the index.html. So the swf path is:
`http://modernlove.co.kr/gatalogview/2014ss_catalog_wide2/swf/gallery02.swf`

You can open the swf on the browser and download it using the shortcut `CTRL+S`.

With the file on your computer you can look inside the swf with the help of Sothink SWF Decompiler or similar.

By this way I've found the XML file path (The same called on the loading screen):

```
var xmlRoute = "swf/galleryInfo.xml"
```

If you open and look at the source code of the XML file located at `http://modernlove.co.kr/gatalogview/2014ss_catalog_wide2/swf/galleryInfo.xml` you will find the images info. With that info you can go directly to the images:

```
http://modernlove.co.kr/gatalogview/2014ss_catalog_wide2/swf/image/img_1.jpg
http://modernlove.co.kr/gatalogview/2014ss_catalog_wide2/swf/image/img_2.jpg
http://modernlove.co.kr/gatalogview/2014ss_catalog_wide2/swf/image/img_3.jpg
http://modernlove.co.kr/gatalogview/2014ss_catalog_wide2/swf/image/img_4.jpg
http://modernlove.co.kr/gatalogview/2014ss_catalog_wide2/swf/image/img_5.jpg
http://modernlove.co.kr/gatalogview/2014ss_catalog_wide2/swf/image/img_6.jpg
http://modernlove.co.kr/gatalogview/2014ss_catalog_wide2/swf/image/img_7.jpg
```

In the same XML file you will also know that are 34 images.

I hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks!! This helped a lot! I actually got to the swf file and tried to extract its content with Sothink SWF Decompiler but it said the file was crashed, so thanks so much for linking to the XML file, it was a great help! ^_^

Comment: You are welcome. If it was helpful to you please mark this answer as your accepted answer. Have a nice day